# modelSetter doesn't assign $scope.profileImage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried implementing file upload [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/).

However, when called `$scope.uploadProfile`, `file` is always `undefined`.
Why this value is not assign on `$scope.profileImage`?

**Update** :

The `$scope.profileImage` is became null or undefined though I added `scope` in *fileModel* directive.

**Update 2** :

It works well when I removed `scope` object in directive `fileModel`. But I don't know why the `$scope.profileImage` is become as `null` or `undefined` wheather `scope` exists.

```js
 app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope : {uploadAfterChanged : '&uploadAfterChanged'},
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
             var changedCallback = attrs.uploadAfterChanged;
             var modelSetter = model.assign;
             
             element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                        // assign to $scope.profileImage
                     modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     scope.uploadAfterChanged();
                 });
                 
             });
         }
     };
 }]);

 app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
     this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, success, error){
         var fd = new FormData();

         if(success === undefined)
          success = function(){};
         if(error === undefined)
          error = function(){};
         
         fd.append('file', file);
         $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
         })
         .success(success)
         .error(error);
     }
 }]);



 app.controller("MySettingCtrl", ['$scope', '$state', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, $state, fileUpload) {
  $scope.goInterestStock = function(){
   $state.go('.interest');
  }
  $scope.goHoldingStock = function(){
   $state.go('.holding');
  }
  $scope.goPersonalTalk = function() {
   $state.go('.talk');
  }
  
  $scope.uploadProfile = function(){
    var file = $scope.profileImage; // file is undefined
    
         console.log('file is ' );
         console.dir(file);
         var uploadUrl = "/user/uploadProfilePhoto.do?callback=test";
         fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, function (){
          $state.reload();
         });

  }
 }]);
```

```html
  <span class="file-wrapper pointer">
<!--    <input type="file" name="sub_market_image_list" id="sub_market_image_list" onchange="previewImage(this,'previewId_1')"> -->
   <span class="btn_upload" onclick="$('#profileFile').click();"><i class="fa fa-camera pointer"></i></span>
   <input type="file" id="profileFile" name="profileFile" style="display:none;" file-model="profileImage" upload-after-changed="uploadProfile()">
  </span>
```

Comment: $scope.profileImage is also undefined

Comment: @Sajeetharan But the code I followed also not exists, and I had tried that you said as `$scope.profileImage = null;` but it's result is also `file == null`